# How do I listen for the (x) button in a UITextField?

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

There's a tiny  button inside editable text `UITextField`s that clears the text. I want to listen for this to, say, reset the text `"$0.00"` instead of `""`, to close the dialog automatically, etc. **How can I listen for this button to be pressed?**

[image: A white x inside a gray, filled circle on the right of a text field in an iOS table.]

Comment: are you sure that's a table view? I think that's in a text field?

Comment: @MrT Sorry, you're right. Edited, but the question still applies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your text field's delegate, implement [`textFieldShouldClear:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldClear:). From the documentation:

> The text field calls this method in response to the user pressing the built-in clear button.

### UPDATE

It sounds like you want to write this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.text = @"";
    [self textFieldDidClear:textField];
    return NO;
}

- (void)textFieldDidClear {
    // To be overridden by subclasses.
}
```

Comment: Alright, sweet, no I'm listening. But no matter what I do, the field is cleared directly after. Is there a way to perform an action _after_ the field is cleared?

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero Update your question with your `textFieldShouldClear:` method. Most likely you are returning `YES` instead of `NO` after setting the text field to your specific value.

Comment: I was, yes. I'm hoping to pull this up into our general text field class so the behavior propagates down through a generic `textFieldWasCleared` delegate method, but only to those who care. For those who don't care, the field should be cleared, and for those who do, they should be allowed to take an appropriate action knowing that the field is now cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Don't, instead set your cell as the delegate and when the text is updated to be an empty string you can deny the edit and directly set your text.

Comment: How do I differentiate this from the user simply pressing backspace until the text is cleared?

Comment: You could differentiate by the existing text when the delegate method fires, if it's more that 1 character long

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... How can I tell if they pressed this button, versus them tapping backspace until there is no text left in the field?